# How to convert a Adobe Photoshop Document (PSD) files into your project as vector drawable resources

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-assets, android-vectordrawable

Android Studio (2.2 or higher) includes a tool called Vector Asset Studio that helps you add Adobe Photoshop Document (PSD) files into your project as vector drawable resources.

I followed the below link but no luck.

> https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

when i try to convert it what i get is only this

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="200"
    android:viewportWidth="200" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

and it doesn't show any preview in Vector Asset Studio.